# Deploying Maven artifact on Apache HTTP

Tags: apache, maven, web-hosting, artifactory

I am new to web hosting.

I want to use an Apache HTTP server to host the site for my artifact built with Maven.

Since Maven uses protocols like SCP, what else should I require to configure the system?
How should I configure the system so that my artifact is available on my HTTP server?

I could set up Artifactory, but I want to know if it is possible to do so without any other third party artifact management system.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely go for Artifactory. It might look like yet another server to babysit, but eventually it will save you a lot of wheel invention.

Comment: @JBaruch As i understand the docs on Artifactory correct it does not offer a possibility to host the maven project site. Only Nexus Pro offers such feature as far as i know. May be you have link to the docs/feature list of Artifactory where stated different.

Comment: To host your artifacts i would really suggest to use either Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva, but for the project web-sites may be you can use github (if you use git) or a separate Web-Server which hosts the Maven sites.

Comment: @JBaruch I am using Artifactory for hosting my artifacts, but was not sure if that can also host sites.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am going with your second approach: separate Web Server hosting the Maven sites. I am simply running the site:stage goal right now and pointing to the htdocs on Apache server to copy the Maven site files there - not sure if that is the way to do it rather than site deploy.

Comment: You actually don't need  a separate server. Arifactory can serve static content out of a zip file. For example, look at the URL of [this javadoc site](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) - the javadoc is in jar, whih version is determined dynamically.
That should do also for Maven site.

Comment: @JBaruch Thanks for the Javadoc example. "That should do also for Maven site": can you give me some code snippet as to how to push the site to Artifactory? Thanks!

Comment: @Neel we overloaded the original question with whole new content. Let's take it to a new discussion.